# Match XML elements/nodes that contain 'X' with XPath

Tags: wordpress, xpath

I'm using the WP-Property and WP-Property: Importer plugins to manage properties on a WordPress powered website. The importer uses xpath rules to help map fields in an imported XML file to their corresponding field on the site.

e.g. 'Display Address' maps to 'address/full'

I have a set of elements that look like this:

```
<property>
    <feature1>Feature</feature>
    <feature2>Feature</feature>
    <feature3>Feature</feature>
    <feature4>Feature</feature>
    <feature5>Feature</feature>
    <address>
        <full>abc</full>
        <street>def</street>
        <postcode>ghi</postcode>
    </address>
</property>
```

I want to group these together into one entry rather than setting up separate fields for each one, so I'm looking for a means to match feature* but everything I've tried so far seems to have missed the mark. Goes without saying that I've never dabbled with xpath before today!

Comment: Xpath will not do grouping but does the xpath expression   "property//(feature1|feature2|feature3|feature4|feature5)"  get close?  If it displays FeatureFeatureFeatureFeature then I may have a solution for you.

Comment: Without the property// part, I get this thrown back when I preview:

[xxx] => Array
        (
            [0] => Feature
            [1] => Feature
            [2] => Feature
            [3] => Feature
            [4] => Feature

...which is exactly the response I wanted from it :) thank you!

Comment: Well that was lucky!!  I would suggest however, if you have control over the xml you would do better to contain all those featureX nodes under a single <features> element. Then the xpath will be more readable:   "features/*".

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking looking at it this morning, unfortunately it's coming from an external feed that I have no control over. Thanks again though, I'm sure I'll have more xpath questions coming up over the next day or so!